# Data.table: sum between irregular date ranges

Tags: r, data.table

Surveys and fires occurred at irregular intervals in different burn units.
(srv=1 means a survey was done, fire=1 means a fire occurred)
I want calculate how many fires were lighted between surveys, i.e.,
including the year of the survey and going back to one year before the last survey.

```
nyear = 10
units = 4
set.seed(15)

DT <- data.table(
        unit = rep(1:units, each=nyear), 
        year = 2000:(2000+nyear-1), 
        srv = rbinom(nyear*units, 1, 0.4),
        fire = rbinom(nyear*units, 1, 0.3)
    )
DT
```

I can calculate the years elapsed but I have to create a new dataset then join it back to the original data set. Then I cannot figure out out to sum fires between date ranges.

```
DT1 <- DT[srv != 0]             # Drop years without surveys
DT2 <- DT1[, .(year, elapsed = year - shift(year)), by = "unit"] # Use 'shift' to find years elapsed
DT3 <- DT2[DT, on=.(unit, year)]    # join dataset with elapsed time to original dataset
DT3[ , sum(fire), on = .(year >= year, year < year -(elapsed-1)), by="unit"] # Doesn't work
```

Example output follows, where 'nfire' is what I'm after -- in years without surveys it is 'NA', otherwise it provides numbers of fires after the last survey and including current survey year:

```
    unit year elapsed srv fire  nfire
 1:    1 2000      NA   1    1  1
 2:    1 2001      NA   0    0  NA
 3:    1 2002       2   1    1  1
 4:    1 2003       1   1    0  0
 5:    1 2004      NA   0    0  NA
 6:    1 2005       2   1    0  0
 7:    1 2006       1   1    0  1
 8:    1 2007      NA   0    1  NA
 9:    1 2008       2   1    1  2
10:    1 2009       1   1    0  1
11:    2 2000      NA   0    0  NA
12:    2 2001      NA   1    1  NA
```

Comment: What's the output given this random data?

Comment: I edited the question to include output data, thanks

Comment: You said you want to count the number of fires between a survey year (inclusive) through one year before the previous survey year. Looking at unit 1 year 2002, there is a fire in year 2002 and one in the previous-survey-year 2000, which to me suggests `nfire[3]` in your answer should be 2, not 1.

Comment: I am adding the fire in survey year 2002 (=1) to the fire in survey year 2001 (=0), to arrive at nfire=1

Comment: Okay, I think the sentence *"including the year of the survey and going back to one year before the last survey"* may be misleading. To me, *"including the year of the survey"* here means 2002; *"the last survey"* means 2000; so *"one year before the last survey"* means 2000-1 or 1999. I'm guessing that when you say *"one year before"*, you mean 2000+1, so the *before* is from one perspective, not necessarily a chronological one. Right?

Comment: Er, yes, I worded that incorrectly. Should be 'the year after the last survey'. Thanks

Comment: Why isn't unit 1 year 2000 `nfire = 1`? Why is unit 1 year 2003 `nfire = 1`? I think your `elapsed` field is a red herring here ... I'd think `DT[, grp := rev(cumsum(rev(srv == 1))), by = .(unit)][, nfire := sum(fire), by=.(unit, grp)]` is close or a good start, but the sums are different.

Comment: Your solution will work if I do one minor tweak (making nfire 'NA' in years when elapsed =1 NA and srv=1. Many thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

The answer of r2evans works:

```
DT[, grp := rev(cumsum(rev(srv == 1))), by = .(unit)][, nfire := sum(fire), by=.(unit, grp)]
```

Times when surveys occurred (srv ==1) are placed in reverse order then summed cumulatively. The reverse ordering ensures that each survey is grouped with the years that preceded it, and the cumulative summing provides assigns a list of consecutively numbered groups. The outer 'rev' changes the order back to its original organization.

The second part of the statement '[, nfire := sum(fire), by=.(unit, grp)]' is an example of chaining--as I understand it, just a way of introducing more operations in a data.table step without cluttering the first part of the statement. The syntax within is  reasonably intuitive.